# How to sort vector to have minimal distance to another vector efficiently?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two vectors (v1, v2). The values in the vector v2 need to be sorted so that each of them can be identified with a element in v1. The values in v1 and v2 differ slightly but might be switched. In the end I need to do this multiple times, since I need to sort the next v3 according to the sorted v2 and so on.

I thought about looking at the different permutations of v2 for every possible ordering of the values in v2. The minimal sum of the differences to v1 should be the sorting that I want to have. This works in principle but does scale terribly when v1 and v2 get bigger.

This code shows the ordering for a pair of v1, v2.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

def sort(v1,v2):
    
    arr_permutations = np.array(list(itertools.permutations(v2)))

    sum_diff = np.sum(np.abs(arr_permutations - v1), axis=1)

    best_permut = arr_permutations[np.argmin(sum_diff)]

    return best_permut 

v1 = np.array([-0.99418 -0.106364j, -1.005974-0.099054j,
 -0.991923-0.107482j, -0.990868-0.107976j, -0.990558-0.108118j,
 -0.898555+0.035351j])

v2 = np.array([-1.0052  -0.10133j,  -0.993598-0.108516j,
  0.991379-0.109617j, -0.990341-0.110104j, -0.990036-0.110244j, 
 -0.898624+0.032346j])

sort(v1,v2)

Out:  np.array([-0.993598-0.108516j, -1.0052  -0.10133j, 
                -0.990341-0.110104j, -0.990036-0.110244j, 
                 0.991379-0.109617j, -0.898624+0.032346j])
```

In this case the correct ordering is to exchange v2[0] and v2[1] in this specific case. As the values that belong to each other all change a little bit, just looking at one value and finding the individual position closest to the value in v1  is not enough.

Comment: Could you give us the expected result of your example here?

Comment: if the arrays have a statistical meaning, summing the square of distances instead of their absolute values probably makes more sense

Comment: hmm they are eigenvalues of two matrices with one parameter changing slightly. Could be that the square distance are better but the problem remain computationally challenging since taking all permutations is the problem. I thought about starting to sort one value and then go to the next but I can't seem to find a solution that works. :(

Comment: did you forget a comma after the line `v1 = np.array([-0.99418 -0.106364j, -1.005974-0.099054j`? otherwise I get an exception..

Comment: This is a famous problem,its called [Assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem).

Comment: yeah I forgot the comma. Ah okay, I figured that I might be well known. Thank you for identifying it. I am somewhat relieved that it is not NP-hard. Do you have a specific idea how this could be implemented in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my try:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

def match(v1, v2, dist):
    assert v1.ndim == v2.ndim == 1
    assert v1.shape[0] == v2.shape[0]
    n = v1.shape[0]
    t = np.dtype(dist(v1[0], v2[0]))
    dist_matrix = np.fromiter((dist(x1, x2) for x1 in v1 for x2 in v2),
                              dtype=t, count=n*n).reshape(n, n)
    row_ind, col_ind = optimize.linear_sum_assignment(dist_matrix)
    return v2[col_ind]

v1 = np.array([-0.99418 -0.106364j, -1.005974-0.099054j, -0.991923-0.107482j,
               -0.990868-0.107976j, -0.990558-0.108118j, -0.898555+0.035351j])
v2 = np.array([-1.0052  -0.10133j,  -0.993598-0.108516j,  0.991379-0.109617j,
               -0.990341-0.110104j, -0.990036-0.110244j, -0.898624+0.032346j])

v2_matched = match(v1, v2, lambda x1, x2: abs(x1 - x2))
print(repr(v2_matched))
# =>
# array([-0.993598-0.108516j, -1.0052  -0.10133j , -0.990341-0.110104j,
#        -0.990036-0.110244j,  0.991379-0.109617j, -0.898624+0.032346j])
```

The output is the same as that of your `sort()`.

As you see, you can plug in a different lambda or function for the distance.

I'm no expert of numpy, there might be a shortcut for calculating the distance matrix `dist_matrix`.

Thanks to @Jonas for identifying the “[assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem)”.

Comment: So dist is my cost matrix and the linear_sum_assignement is from scipy.optimize right? I will try to implement it and see if it works.

 BTW how do you attribute solutions taken from stack overflow in your code. Shouldn't I rightly say something in the documentation "solution by Walter Tross" or something like that.

Comment: Yes, dist, which I now renamed `dist_matrix` for clarity, is the cost matrix for `scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment()`. As for the attribution, the real work has been done by the contributors to scipy and numpy, so it's not needed. If you want the link to a solution, it's provided by the “share” button at its bottom left.

Comment: glad to know, but... woops, the type of `dist_matrix` was wrong (complex, in your case). It worked because all complex numbers in there have 0 imaginary part. I've fixed it now. The type is taken from the first distance, in order to stay generic.

Comment: ... and I had forgotten the imports :-(